# JQuery: How to clone an element into it's own child

Tags: jquery, menu, clone, parent

I'm working on a mobile-menu (based on [this](http://tympanus.net/Development/ResponsiveMultiLevelMenu/)) where I want to clone a parent [LI] element into it's own child [UL], after an element with a specific class.

Problem 01: The first problem is that I can clone the elements based on a simple CSS selector, but it clones ALL of the iterations of that element, not just the single relevant parent element... in other words, I end up cloning EVERY parent into EVERY child [UL].

Problem 02: I also just want to clone the [LI] and it's child [A] element... not the child [UL] element that we're cloning into. I can't seem to isolate just the parent [LI] and it's child [A] element when I run the clone... There's no sense in also cloning the child UL element into itself as that'd pretty much just create an infinite loop of child menus (which, would be kinda funny, but not useful)

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Here's my markup:

```
<ul class="dl-menu">
    <li>
         <a href="#">Parent Item 1</a>
         <ul class="dl-submenu">
             <li class="dl-back">BACK</li>
             <!-- This is where I want to add just the one cloned parent LI -->
             <li><a href="">Child Item 1A</a></li>
             <li><a href="">Child Item 1B</a></li>
             <li><a href="">Child Item 1C</a></li>
         </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
         <a href="#">Parent Item 2</a>
         <ul class="dl-submenu">
             <li class="dl-back">BACK</li>
             <!-- This is where I want to add just the one cloned parent LI -->
             <li><a href="">Child Item 2A</a></li>
             <li><a href="">Child Item 2B</a></li>
             <li><a href="">Child Item 2C</a></li>
         </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
         <a href="#">Parent Item 3</a>
         <ul class="dl-submenu">
             <li class="dl-back">BACK</li>
             <!-- This is where I want to add just the one cloned parent LI -->
             <li><a href="">Child Item 3A</a></li>
             <li><a href="">Child Item 3B</a></li>
             <li><a href="">Child Item 3C</a></li>
         </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I've tried all manner of outlandish ideas, but here's my existing script in it's most raw form just to give you an idea to start with:

```
function clone_menu_parent(){
    $(this).clone().insertAfter(".dl-back");
}
$('.dl-menu > li').each(clone_menu_parent);
```

Thanks to anyone that might have a clue!

EDIT: I suppose it would be helpful to also give the markup that I WANT to have at the end:

```
<ul class="dl-menu">
    <li>
         <a href="#">Parent Item 1</a>
         <ul class="dl-submenu">
             <li class="dl-back">BACK</li>
             <li><a href="">Parent Item 1</a></li>
             <li><a href="">Child Item 1A</a></li>
             <li><a href="">Child Item 1B</a></li>
             <li><a href="">Child Item 1C</a></li>
         </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
         <a href="#">Parent Item 2</a>
         <ul class="dl-submenu">
             <li class="dl-back">BACK</li>
             <li><a href="">Parent Item 2</a></li>
             <li><a href="">Child Item 2A</a></li>
             <li><a href="">Child Item 2B</a></li>
             <li><a href="">Child Item 2C</a></li>
         </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
         <a href="#">Parent Item 3</a>
         <ul class="dl-submenu">
             <li class="dl-back">BACK</li>
             <li><a href="">Parent Item 3</a></li>
             <li><a href="">Child Item 3A</a></li>
             <li><a href="">Child Item 3B</a></li>
             <li><a href="">Child Item 3C</a></li>
         </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Naturally, it'd be great if this works for any LI element with a UL as a child... so that you could have the menu work for 3, 4, 5, + levels of depth.

Final Edit:

The solution that worked best (thanks to btm1 for the creative idea to work backwards from an internal element), thanks in part to everyone that contributed something to this:

```
$(".dl-back").each(function(){
    var parent = $(this).parents('li');   
    var copy = parent.clone();
    $(copy).find(".dl-submenu").remove().end();     
    $(this).after(copy);
});
```

I'll note that there are some other excellent ideas for cloning into a child below... if you're in a similar situation but the fix provided by btm1 doesn't work (ie: you can't work backwards from an internal element because it's not well defined), check the other answers below as they are perfectly viable alternatives if you don't have special reqs like I did ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go the other way and each the dl-black to find the parent.

```
$(".dl-back").each(function(){
   var parent = $(this).parents('li');
   var copy = parent.next().clone().wrap('<li></li>');

   $(this).after(copy);
});
```

Comment: Oh that's sneaky... I didn't even consider that. That works perfect, except it doesn't strip the parent's child UL... I'll see what I can do with this as a new starting point. Any tips would be great :)

Comment: hmm i can probably help you figure it out but i'm not sure what you mean... strip the parents child ul?

Comment: <li>
         <a href="#">Parent Item 1</a>
         <ul class="dl-submenu"> <----- you want this one stripped? like removed for everything inside it cleared out?
             <li class="dl-back">BACK</li>
             <li><a href="">Parent Item 1</a></li>
             <li><a href="">Child Item 1A</a></li>
             <li><a href="">Child Item 1B</a></li>
             <li><a href="">Child Item 1C</a></li>
         </ul>
    </li>

Comment: Correct - Right now, when you duplicate the child `<ul class="dl-menu">...</ul>`, it just creates another child menu underneath it when what I want is just the `li` and `a`, like this: `<li><a href="my_parent_url">ParentItem</a></li>`. 


PS... THANKS! I'm incredibly stoked that I've made more progress in 15 minutes here than I did in the last 4 hours of way crazier looking ideas.

Comment: Like that?(i made an edit to my code block)  you mean you want an LI wrapper around the link you've inserted after dl-black? or you want the link to be placed inside dl-black?

Comment: That didn't do it, but a variation of your original code did! I'll add it to my original post at the bottom for what it looks like (and then copy it to your answer for posterity?).

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you want to clone the `<a>` element from the top most `li` elemnts into the child `ul` elements.  that being said why not use this as your selector:

```
 function clone_menu_parent(){
      $(this).find("a").clone().insertAfter(".dl-back");
 }
 $('.dl-menu > li').each(clone_menu_parent);
```

if you run into issues finding the correct `<a>` elements just add a class designator like `a.FindMe` and chenge the find call to `.find("a.FindMe")`.

Edit:: after seeing your desired output try changing the function to something like this:

```
 function clone_menu_parent(){
      var link = $(this).find("a");
      var linkhtml = link.outerHTML;
      $(this).find(".dl-submenu > .dl-back").after("<li>" + linkhtml + "</li>");
 }
```

Comment: Good try! The entire `li` and `a` combo needs to be cloned... not just the `a`... and this still clones every `a` into every child (the scope of `.each` gives me some headaches... it looks fine to me when I look at it, but I'm apparently missing something as it's not drilling down on just the one element).

Comment: Awesome! Much closer - now it's just missing the actual link... what I get now is basically `<li>Parent Item</li>`, when what I want is `<li><a href="my_parent_url">ParentItem</a></li>`.

This is super close... I'll tinker with it unless you see an obvious way to get the link in there (I tried replacing linkhtml with just link, but it returns [object Object]).

Comment: @BrandonJones hmmmmm ok a way to do that would be in my edit.

Comment: Odd - that works for the first parent/child combo... the rest after that turn up "undefined" inside the spot we're cloning to. I'll tinker with it... I'm guessing that it's hitting a hiccup when it hits an item without any children.

Answer (score 0):

I took your code and pasted it into a fiddle then made an answer

**[Here you go](http://jsfiddle.net/gillyspy/XM4ez/)**

```
$('.dl-menu > li > a').each( function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $newLI = $('<li>').append( $this.clone() );
    $newLI.insertAfter(    $this.next('ul').find('.dl-back') );
}); // end on click
```

Comment: So far this has been the closest... the only issue I can see if that it doesn't work on the 3rd level - the 1st level parent item continues to clone after the back button even on the 3rd level, like this (edit, I can't get the markup to format properly... so I'm hoping you follow me ;) )